# how to create a button to learn a javascript function but the page cannot be refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps-api-3

```js
function showFeature(geojson, style){
   currentFeature_or_Features = new GeoJSON(geojson, style || null);
   if (currentFeature_or_Features.type && currentFeature_or_Features.type == "Error"){
    document.getElementById("put_geojson_string_here").value = currentFeature_or_Features.message;
    return;
   }
   if (currentFeature_or_Features.length){
    for (var i = 0; i < currentFeature_or_Features.length; i++){
     if(currentFeature_or_Features[i].length){
      for(var j = 0; j < currentFeature_or_Features[i].length; j++){
       currentFeature_or_Features[i][j].setMap(map);
       if(currentFeature_or_Features[i][j].geojsonProperties) {
        setInfoWindow(currentFeature_or_Features[i][j]);
       }
      }
     }
     else{
      currentFeature_or_Features[i].setMap(map);
     }
     if (currentFeature_or_Features[i].geojsonProperties) {
      setInfoWindow(currentFeature_or_Features[i]);
     }
    }
   }else{
    currentFeature_or_Features.setMap(map)
    if (currentFeature_or_Features.geojsonProperties) {
     setInfoWindow(currentFeature_or_Features);
    }
   }
   
   document.getElementById("put_geojson_string_here").value = JSON.stringify(geojson);
  }
```

I am developing a application that can show the point in the map using google maps api and php but i had a button if you clique for searching the page refreshed i would that if i search the point (var geojson_parce) the page show the result (showFeature(geojson_parce,adressStyle) but not be refreshed (tourned). please if you have a solution help me

```html
<?php 

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "postgres"; 
$password = "20152016"; 
$db = "Projet"; 

$con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$password")
    or die ("Could not connect to server\n");  
?> 
<h4>Afficher par nom:</h4>
<form>
<input type="text" name="term" /><br />  
<input type="submit" Onclick="showFeature(geojson_parce,adressStyle);"></input>  
</form>
<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {

$term = pg_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);     

$sql = "SELECT row_to_json(fc)
 FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
 FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type
    , ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geometry)::json As geometry
    , row_to_json(lp) As properties
   FROM poi As lg
         INNER JOIN (SELECT id, description FROM poi WHERE nom LIKE '%".$term."%') As lp 
       ON lg.id = lp.id  ) As f )  As fc;"; 
$result = pg_query($con, $sql);
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
    foreach($row as $rslt);
?>
  var geojson_barrage=<?php
        echo $rslt;
  
} }?>;
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing, and what is your question?

Comment: Change the button type from `submit` to `button`

Comment: i would that if i search the point (var geojson_parce) the page show the result (showFeature(geojson_parce,adressStyle) but not be refreshed (tourned)

Comment: @RamRaider i doing it but he cannot show the point?!

Comment: Ok - you would need to do some other stuff too - I will explain an answer

Comment: @RamRaider ok but i don't undertsand your answer

Comment: Was "Google Translate" used for translating the question from another language? Looks that way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want to do ( get details from the db to show markers on the map without reloading the page ) you would need to restructure your code and utilise ajax.

Currently the submission of the form will set the variable `$term` which is then used in the sql query but obviously this has the negative side effect of reloading the page.

The best way to achieve what you want to do is to send a POST request via Ajax to your script that will send the json response back to your javascript function - and NOT reload the page as it is asynchronous.

The following code snippets are not tested but they should give you the idea of what I mean.

```
/*
    At the top of your php page, this php code will get the data
    from the database when it receives a POST request:
*/

<?php
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $user = "postgres"; 
    $password = "20152016"; 
    $db = "Projet"; 

    $con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$password") or die ("Could not connect to server\n"); 


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /* get the POSTed variables from your ajax call and query the database */

        @ob_clean();

        $term = isset( $_POST['term'] ) && !empty( $_POST['term'] ) ? $_POST['term'] : false;
        if( !$term ) exit( json_encode( array('error'=>'Search term was empty') ) );

        $sql = "select row_to_json(fc)
                from ( select 'featurecollection' as type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) as features
                from ( select 'feature' as type, st_asgeojson(lg.geometry)::json as geometry, row_to_json(lp) as properties
                from poi as lg inner join ( select id, description from poi where nom like '%".$term."%') as lp 
                on lg.id = lp.id  ) as f )  as fc;";

                /* Query db */
                $result = pg_query($con, $sql);

                /* Process the recordset and construct your data response */

                /* 
                   send json data: it is this data that YOUR showFeature
                   function uses. It equates to "http.responseText" 
                   in the ajax function
                */
                header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8",true);
                echo $data;
        exit();
    }

    /* Any other code below ... */
?>
```

In the `HEAD` section where your javascript is:

```
    <script>
        /* How / where is this set? */
        var adressStyle;


        function showFeature(geojson, style){
            var node=document.getElementById("put_geojson_string_here");
            var cff = new GeoJSON( geojson, style || null );

            if (cff.type && cff.type == "Error"){
                node.value = cff.message;
                return;
            }
            if( cff.length ){
                for( var i = 0; i < cff.length; i++ ){
                    if( cff[i].length ){
                        for( var j = 0; j < cff[i].length; j++ ){
                            cff[i][j].setMap(map);
                            if( cff[i][j].geojsonProperties ) setInfoWindow( cff[i][j] );
                        }
                    } else{
                        cff[i].setMap(map);
                    }
                    if( cff[i].geojsonProperties ) setInfoWindow( cff[i] );
                }
            } else {
                cff.setMap(map)
                if( cff.geojsonProperties ) setInfoWindow( cff );
            }
            node.value = JSON.stringify( geojson );
        }

        function getdata(){
            /* ajax */
            var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
            var headers={
                'Accept':"text/html, application/xml, application/json, text/javascript, "+"*"+"/"+"*"+"; charset=utf-8",
                'Content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
            };

            /* Assign a callback listener for when the data is received */
            http.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if( http.readyState==4 && http.status==200 ) showFeature.call( this, http.responseText, adressStyle );
            }

            /* Open the POST request */
            http.open( 'POST', document.location.href, true );

            /* Send some headers - Content-Type is important */
            for( header in headers ) http.setRequestHeader( header, headers[ header ] );

            /* Actually send the request variables */
            http.send( 'term='+document.getElementById('term').value );
        }
    </script>
```

And the html form

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id='term' name="term" /><br />  
    <input type="button" onclick="getdata();" value='Submit query' />    
</form>
```

So, the user clicks the button ( which does not now submit the form in the traditional sense ) which sends an AJAX POST request to the same page - the request is handled by the PHP code above ( it only gets executed if the request is a POST request though you might want to add other conditions to that ) and the PHP code queries the database, processes the recordset and echoes back the json data which is used to add the markers to the map. Your original javascript function `showFeature` is acting now as the `callback` to the ajax request but, as it wasn't shown in your question, I do not know how it works or what it does exactly.

Comment: if you can change all the code because i can't show it,,,? :/

Answer (score 0):

Write the `showFeature()` function as this:

```
function showFeature(event,geojson_parce,adressStyle){
    event.preventDefault();
    //...do rest of function
}
```

and the call will be

`onclick = "showFeature(event,geojson_parce,adressStyle)"`

Calling `preventDefault()` on the `event` object will prevent the page from refreshing when clicking submit.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: @SteveCroHunter can you help i don't undertand can you termine the function js?

Answer (score 0):

The page is getting refresh because of submit button in for. To prevent page load you need to unbind submit in form. You can achieve this by following ways,

1. `<input type="button" onclick="showFeature(geojson_parce,adressStyle);">Search</input>`
2. At the end of this function *showFeature* just add.

   ```
   return false;
   ```
3. or like below as well

   `<input type="button" onclick="showFeature(geojson_parce,adressStyle); return false;">Search</input>`

Hope this helps to you.